# Strange case of Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess I have this rule among other similars

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^Buscar view/buscar.php
    RewriteRule ^Ordendecompra  view/ordendecompra.php
```

Apache (2.4.4 Win64 OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.15) change Ordendecompra for Ordendecompra/ with  Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently

But in web hosting don't have this error.

I solved it by changing

```
    RewriteRule ^Ordendecomp  view/ordendecompra.php
```

But I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. *nix by defaul is case sensitive but windows dont. The web server inheritance this condition.